# Rhythem Theme for Drupal Commerce

Tags: theming, commerce

Hi does anyone here use Rhythm Theme for Drupal Commerce. I have a problem when I upgrade to the latest version of commerce in that when I go to create a Product Display it only lists 10 products instead of the many products I have. Not sure if this is a problem with commerce or with the theme I am using.

Comment: Have you tested with another theme? Or else test with a blank template.php file. The only way it can be the theme is if there are some Views overrides in the template.php file or any other file it references.

Comment: I have just tried with Bartick and still have the same problem so I assume it must be commerce. Will log an issue with them thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is actually due to a change in Commerce 1.13 that we didn't have a great way to overcome initially. (More information at: https://www.drupal.org/node/2697017). The issue is with the settings for the product reference field on your node type. If you edit it, you'll find an options list limit setting that you can increase to see the more complete list of products again. Sorry for the regression. :-/